# Generating XAML and bitmap from vectorial shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, vector-graphics

I would like to generate vectorial shapes in various output formats: bmp, png, svg and XAML.
So basically, this is a library (no user interface) which generate internally a vectorial shape in order to export it.
The shape I want to export might contain a combination of rectangle, lines, text and circle.

But I don't know which way to choose in order to handle all those formats (bitmap and vectorial) easily.

So far, I have considered:

- Building programmatically the shape with XAML. Example; create a
  Rectangle(), add it to a Canvas(). From there, it is very easy to
  generate the XAML and to render the images. But I'm not sure that it
  is fast.
- Use System.Windows.Media methods to draw my shapes. But how to generate XAML (and svg)?
- Use GDI+ methods (System.Drawing). Like the preceding point, I'm stuck when generating XAML.

Maybe there is another way to generate my vectorial shape and then export it?

Thank you

Comment: You're probably looking for `Path`, but it's hard to tell because you've given no details about the shape you're generating. Does it consist solely of rectangles, or are there curves or arbitrary polygons? Is it a single shape filled with a single color, or could there be multiple shapes each with its own color? Give some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Joe. I have edited my question to specify more in detail the shape I want to generate. It's more complex than just a circle or a rectangle, it can be a rectangle + a circle + a text + a line for instance.